# How to get TeamCity Build Name?

Tags: powershell, teamcity, microsoft-teams

I have numerous builds setup in TeamCity under a project.  This is one such build below:
[image: TeamCity General Settings]

I am trying to use the "Name" under General Settings in PowerShell script which sends a message via a webhook to a MS Teams channel.  I have tried looking everywhere to find someplace from which to pull this build name...system variables, etc.  It seems as though there is a variable for everything in TeamCity except this name field.  There is even an endpoint for the TeamCity API which I am using to pull the build status, but not for this.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this build name field?

Comment: When TeamCity runs a commandline / powershell step it provides an environment variable ```TEAMCITY_BUILD_PROPERTIES_FILE``` set to the path to an xml file which contains all of the build parameters. You can read that in PowerShell with, e.g. ```$properties = [xml] (Get-Content -Path $env:TEAMCITY_BUILD_PROPERTIES_FILE -Raw)``` and then extract the build configuration name from there.

Comment: I'll try that after my morning meetings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @mclayton's suggestion from the comments, I pulled the XML via PowerShell and saw there is a setting in there called:

```
%system.teamcity.buildConfName%
```

I was able to successfully use that to grab the build name without parsing the XML.

```
$buildName = "%system.teamcity.buildConfName%"
```

It was that simple once I knew what it was called!